# Installing libav 10 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multimedia, avconv, libav

I need libav version 10 or higher.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.0.3.  I have versions 9.18-6 installed.

Looking at https://libav.org/download/ - I see some source files I could try to compile - but I'd rather not mess around with that.

Is there a PPA or .deb for the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

There's a PPA for libav 11 - the latest version - at https://blueprints.launchpad.net/~heyarje/+archive/ubuntu/libav-11/+index?field.series_filter=